# Listbox items slide show

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

In my application I am consuming a web service and displaying 100 items by using a `ListBox`. It's working fine.

The items are displaying in a single page. But I want to display only 10 items in the 1st slide and if we slide the screen from right to left then next 10 list items should display.

How can we do this in window phone development by using C#?

Is this Concept there in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

There are some options for this issue:

1. You can display data in pivot control and add new pivotItems with ListBox for each 10 items.
2. You can also use StackPanel with `Orientation="Horizontal"` it gives you possibility to slide your content horizontally.

Comment: Already i have tried that one...In Pivot control, If we slide 1st one from left to right then directly we are getting the last slide, which is not a good one. If there is the way to stop rotating it will be good...

Comment: There are no way to stop looping on pivot, so I suggest you to check second solution.